# PHP script to parse HTML email for each value greater than a set number

Tags: php, parsing, email

I have order confirmation html emails being parsed by a PHP script. The script does a few things successfully but I can't work out how to get it to search through the email for all product prices, and then to set a flag if the value is greater than £500.

Basically, I'd like the script to send me an email alert if an order is over £500.

Below is what I have so far. $body is the content of the HTML email. I know that part works as the other rules are setup fine. I think my problem is the $pattern rules for preg_match - I don't think it's identifying the price values correctly.

Is there a way I can search $body for anything with the format of £xx.xx (where each x is a number) and add 1 to $temp for each value it finds that is greater than £500? I can't work this out...

```
if (stristr($body,'Order Confirmation') !== false) {

    $string = $body;

    $pattern = '/^[0-9]{1,}$/';

    preg_match ($pattern, $string, $matches);

    $temp =  array_filter($matches, function($value) {
        return $value >= 500;
    });

if ($temp >= 1)
{
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Robot<robot@robot.com>";
    mail('joe@blogs.com','Internet Order Value Over £500', $body, $headers);
}

}
```

Comment: `{1,}` can be simplified with `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. the code should work if you copy-and-paste into a file with a php extension. You'll have to edit it slightly for your script.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bla.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$string = "lots of things here oh look a price in bold <b>£656.00</b> then more things oh wow";

$pattern = '~<b>£([^<]*).([^<]*)</b>~'; //pattern to find the price in-between the <b></b> tags in $string

preg_match ($pattern, $string, $matches);

$price = substr($matches[0],5); // removes the <b>£ bits from the match if present

if ($price >= 500.00) // if statement to determine if greater than a value
{
echo "value is greater than £500";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```